# Why does the link tag sometimes not work while style tag works?

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

I was playing with Path 2.0 flying menu (http://codepen.io/sparanoid/pen/nHAmi) earlier and realized once I remove the link style tag from the index.html and put them into css files to link back to the file, the web page doesn't work as it was before anymore.

The link tag I use is very standard:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css"/>
```

This link tag replaces the second style tags in the example files. I searched online and there is no documentations about some condition when only the style tag could work.

I suspect that the reason might be prefixfree.js cannot interpret css files (but can interpret style tags). I wonder if that's the reason, how I can set up correct interpreter for prefixfree.js.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try not to use prefixFree. It's a buggy plugin. It doesn't always work with webkit based browser such as Safari, Chrome, or Opera even when set up a remove server (and certainly do not work when using local files).

Comment: :) Try searching for prefix generator. You can turn your stylesheet in and generate them automatically without using any plugins.

Answer (score 0):

There are two reasons why this might break:

- Browser can't download the file.
- The order of style sheets matter.

Look into your browser's error log. If you see an error there, fix it.

If there is no error, then there is a problem with the order of the styles. Later styles overwrite earlier ones. Try to move the `<link>` element to see how that changes things or use your browser's developer tools to see which styles get applied.

Comment: Thanks Aaron. I am aware of these two situations so I have debugged before asking the questions. Neither of these two were the reason because: 1. I can see the file being loaded in chrome's inspector, and elements are properly styled. 2. The order of the style sheets didn't change. I simply replaced one big block of style tag with a css file (and there is only one css file anyway - another being removable normalizer).

Comment: I think it might has to do with prefixfree.js not able to convert css files (and if so, how do I set up prefixfree.js to convert a css file?) Thanks.

Comment: The docs of `prefixfree.js` say: "Processes every stylesheet in <link> or <style> elements ..." [link](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/). Is there anything in the console? Maybe the CSS is broken in some odd way?

Comment: No. Nothing. So I was wondering if that was the problem. I comment out the prefixfree.js and the document broke too just like when I replace the style tag with the link tag - this is why I thought it was the reason.